# NestJS question: Is the purpose of the schema.gql file simply for facilitating a transition from "code first" to "schema first" development?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

We are developing our NestJs application using a "code first" development process.

I am trying to understand how the NestJs GraphQLModule wraps Apollo Server.  From what I am observing, the schema is generated at runtime and is passed in a configuration object to the Apollo Server.

However, the GraphQLModule also generates a *schema.gql* file.  I cannot see how this would be used for Apollo Server, directly.

My assumption is that the schema.gql file is generated **simply** to facilitate a transition from "code first" to "schema first" development.

**Question**: is this assumption correct?

Comment: ready, prepared answer for 'introspection query' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be to help transition to a schema-first design. It could also be to allow for automatic SDK generation based off of the schema file that gets created. There are codegen tools that can read a `.gql` file and create an entire API for your front end/client application, that can easily consume the GraphQL API in a type-safe manner.

I wouldn't really transition from code-first to schema-first or vice-versa, because you already have some typescript files based off of what you want your schema to be. No big reason to switch if what you're dealing with works, right?